# Conjecture: there are more than $\pi(p)$ primes between consecutive prime squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, prime-gaps

For any $p_i$ (being the $i$th prime), it seems empirically certain that

$$\pi(p_{i+1}^2)-\pi(p_i^2)>i.$$

Equivalently: there are more than $\pi(p)$ primes between any $p^2$ and the next higher prime squared. I *think* that for large enough $p$, this would be strictly stronger than [Legendre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture), Oppermann, etc., and someone yell at me if that's wrong.

**I realize conjectures of this type currently remain famously unresolved; my question is whether this one in particular has been noted before, and if so, where/who by.**

If I'm mistaken and someone spots a counterexample, that would also work as an answer.

---

###### Observations

I've now checked this for $i$ up to $~22000$, so all primes up to $250000$, meaning $p^2$ is hitting $~6.5\times 10^{10}$. Looking at the last few thousand intervals, we see:

- Mean number of primes in an interval is $\approx 250000$.
- Max number of primes seen in an interval was $1424502$.
- Min number of primes seen in an interval was $36352$.

I find it notable that the minimums that far out are still $<2i$, meaning it's staying closer than I would have guessed. This also confirms that this conjecture is a *much* stronger claim than the others mentioned. In particular, [Brocard's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_conjecture) uses exactly these intervals, but it only asserts four or more primes in each of them.

From a few spot checks, the lower bound of the ratio $R_i:=\frac{\pi(p_{i+1}^2)-\pi(p_i^2)}{i}$ does seem to grow over time, albeit fairly slowly, giving the following min $R_i$ values for nearby samples of $i$:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
i & R_i \\ \hline
10^2 & 1.68 \\ \hline
10^3 & 1.738  \\ \hline
10^4 & 1.806  \\ \hline
10^5 & 1.842  \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

I'd guess it grows unbounded, but checking anything much larger would require a cleverer approach to the number crunching.

Finally, I assume this behavior is not news to anyone, but the prime count in these intervals averages very closely to the value of $p$. For $1\leq i \leq 10000$, here are moving averages (50- and 2500-step) of each such ratio $\frac{\pi(p_{i+1}^2)-\pi(p_i^2)}{p_i}$ in that range.

[image: lineplot of ratios]

---

##### Edit: simplest broadly equivalent version

...is this, I think. For $n$ large enough,

$$\left(\frac{c+1}{4}\right)\pi(n) < \pi(n^2+n)-\pi(n^2) < \frac{1}{2}\pi(n),$$

where $0 \leq c < 1$ is a constant. $c=0$ requires no lower bound on $n$, but that lower bound increases as $c$ approaches $1$.

(IIRC, $c=2/3$ works for $n>5000$ or thereabouts, as a spot check.)

And if you prefer, I think this is equivalent. I couldn't decide which was better.

$$\left(\frac{c+1}{2}\right)\pi(n) < \pi((n+1)^2)-\pi(n^2) < \pi(n).$$

Comment: If this holds upto , say , $p_i=10^6$, I do not expect a counterexample.  But considering that the best proven upper bound for prime gaps is $p^{0.525}$ for sufficiently large $p$, I neither expect that this conjecture has been proven.

Comment: Your conjecture would follow from the more straightforward conjecture $\pi((x+2)^2)-\pi(x^2) > \pi(x)$, since $p_{i+1}\ge p_i+2$. The right-hand side is asymptotically $x/\log x$. Conjecturally the left-hand side is asymptotically $2x/\log x$, but as Peter alluded to, this is still an open problem. And no, I don't see any reason to believe that anybody has noted your particular conjecture, nor my generalization.

Comment: @GregMartin If you'd copy it over, I'd accept this as an answer. (I wish people wouldn't always answer in comments, especially when it's helpful... even if short!)