# Conjecture on ordering the first $p^2$ naturals by prime factor count

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers, conjectures, prime-gaps

Let $\text{bump}(n)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ be a function that increases the prime index of each prime factor of $n$ (with multiplicity) by $1$. I'll also use the notation $\text{bump}^k(n)$ to signify $\text{bump}(\text{bump}(\ldots))$ composed $k$ times, with the upshot that $\text{bump}^k(n)$ increases each prime factor of $n$, shifting up by $k$ primes.

e.g. $\text{bump}^2(20)=\text{bump}^2(2^2\cdot 5)=\text{bump}^2(p_1^2\cdot p_3)=p_{1+2}^2\cdot p_{3+2}=5^2\cdot 11=275$.

###### Properties

*I don't think these are strictly related to my question, but am including them just in case.*

- $\text{bump}^{-k}(n)$ serves as an inverse where applicable.

  - For example, $\text{bump}^{-2}(35)=6$, but $\text{bump}^{-3}(35)$ is undefined since it would return $p_0 p_1$.
- $\text{bump}^{-k}(\text{bump}^k(n))=n$ works just fine for all nonnegative $k$.
- $\text{bump}$ is totally multiplicative: $\text{bump}(a) \cdot \text{bump}(b) = \text{bump}(ab)$.

  - $\gcd(\text{bump}(a),\text{bump}(b))=\text{bump}(\gcd(a,b))$.
- $\text{bump}(x)$ gives distinct values for all $x$ in its domain.
- $\text{bump}(1)=1$.
- $\text{bump}(\mathbb N)$ is the set of all odd naturals.

#### Conjecture

Let $S=\{s \in \mathbb N : 2 \leq s \leq p_i^2\}$, for some prime $p_i$.

Let $R=\text{bump}^i(S)$. I claim that for any two elements $a,b$ in $R$,

$$\Omega(a) < \Omega(b) \implies a < b,$$

where $\Omega$ is a function counting factors with multiplicity.

**Informally,** the conjecture is that if you $\text{bump}$ all the integers in $[2,p_i^2]$ by $i$ or more, and sort the resulting list, the first (smallest) numbers will be every prime in the list, followed by every semiprime in the list, then every 3-almost prime, and so forth. Each group is contiguous; the largest $m$-almost prime will be strictly smaller than the smallest $(m+1)$-almost prime, for all $m$.

---

Small example using $i=2$.

$R=\text{bump}^2(S)$, where $S=[2,p_i^2]=\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

Table is displayed sorted by values in $R$.

[image]

---

Larger example using $i=5$. First column is input ($S$), second is $\text{bump}$ed output ($R$). Tables are separated by factor count for visibility (leftmost is all primes, to the right semiprimes, etc.), but logically it is one long table. You'll see $R$ is ordered as in our last example (e.g. $149$ at the end of the first table precedes $169$ beginning the second table).

[image: bump example]

---

I am nearly certain this holds in light of empirical observations and heuristics. Furthermore, it is clear that $i$ is necessarily the smallest sufficient factor-shifting value, as $\text{bump}^{i-1}(S)$ will include $p_i^2$ along with $i-1$ primes larger than $p_i^2$ in the resulting output set, violating the ordering.

However, this assumes that commonly held beliefs about the distribution of primes are true—in particular, the Legendre conjecture or a roughly equivalent result. For this reason, I expect that proving my conjecture above would be insurmountably difficult for the moment, as it implies a [substantially stronger claim](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4408756/conjecture-there-are-more-than-pip-primes-between-consecutive-prime-square) than Legendre, itself a conjecture which is still famously unresolved.

Given that, my question is whether a relaxed version of this conjecture might be more amenable to proof. For example, instead of $\text{bump}^i(S)$, one could consider adding a constant $c$ such as in the following (progressively weaker) expressions for what is sufficient to guarantee ordering-by-factors:

- $\text{bump}^{i+c}(S)$
- $\text{bump}^{ci}(S)$
- $\text{bump}^{i^{c}}(S)$
- $\text{bump}^{c^{i}}(S)$

It should be apparent with a little thought that $\Omega(a)<\Omega(b) \iff \text{bump}^k(a)<\text{bump}^k(b)$ as $k\to \infty$. This is because in the limit, the difference between factors will become negligible; regardless of the initial argument $n$, as $k\to\infty$, the ratio between the next term and the current term should converge on something like $\left(\frac{p_{k+1}}{p_{k}}\right)^{\Omega(n)}$.

If I have this right, this implies that in the time it takes for a prime to grow by a factor of $x$, a semiprime will grow by approx. $x^2$, and so on. I suppose that means that $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \left(\frac{\log {\text{bump}^k(a)}}{\log {\text{bump}^k(b)}}\right)=\frac{\Omega(a)}{\Omega(b)},$$ though I'd like to have someone confirm that or not. At any rate, what I have no idea about is whether there are some existing formal treatments of this general principle that could be useful here.

**I will consider this question answered if**: anyone can show a proof of the conjecture with one of those more relaxed expressions listed, if anyone can point me in a useful direction via suggesting relevant theorems, or if anyone can point out a reason that no version of this is likely to be presently provable. Or, of course, if anyone can find a counterexample to my conjecture.

It occurs to me that perhaps this is at least provable for all composite cases in the given range; that would eliminate dealing with the primes, which is the only thing we can be sure would be hard to prove.

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding:  you're claiming that the function $f(n) = \mathrm{bump}(n, i)$ is a bijection from $S$ to its image $R := f(S)$, right?  That much seems clear, since it only says that $f$ is injective.  I don't understand the ordering claim though--what are $a$, $b$, $R_a$, and $R_b$?  In your example, is the claim that all the bumped numbers in one column are less than all the bumped numbers in the next column?

Comment: @RaviFernando Sorry I couldn't be more clear. Yes, in my example, the input set $S$ is every number in all the left columns, and the output set $R$ is every number in all the right columns. I would have listed it as one long table, but thought that would be spammy. And if you look, you'll see $R$, the right column, is completely ordered.

Comment: This could be a very interesting problem, unfortunately I cannot understand the intent. Are  you looking for the smallest numbers having at least a given number of prime factors (multiplicity considered) ?

Comment: @Peter This is for its own sake; I hadn't considered applications yet. At this point, I'm just interested in whether there are some larger expression than $i$, even if it's unwieldly like $2^i$, that can be used with a relatively simple proof to demonstrate the soundness of the approach and serve as a starting point for potential further investigation.

Comment: You meant it's _totally multiplicative_, which is stronger.

Comment: @nickgard - Thanks. I misinterpreted "prime index" to be "prime exponent".

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the claim now--but I don't think $\Omega(R_a) \leq \Omega(R_b) \iff a \leq b$ is what you mean.  (E.g. in your examples, you have $\Omega(R_2) = 1 = \Omega(R_1)$ even though $2 \nleq 1$.)  I think you're claiming that $\mathrm{bump}^i$ is an order-preserving bijection from $S$ to $R$ if $R$ is ordered by size and $S$ is ordered first by $\Omega$ and then by size.  In other words, for elements $m,n \in S$, we have $$(\Omega(m), m) \leq (\Omega(n), n) \iff \mathrm{bump}^i(m) \leq \mathrm{bump}^i(n),$$ using the lexicographic order on the left-hand side.  Is that right?

Comment: (continued) But I think this is false.  For example, if I'm not mistaken, we have $$\mathrm{bump}^6(14) = 17 \cdot 29 = 493 > 437 = 19 \cdot 23 = \mathrm{bump}^6(15).$$

Comment: @RaviFernando I'll have to fix my notation, I'm terrible with it. All I'm really trying to claim is that $R$, ordered by size, will also be ordered by number of factors. I.e. every prime in $R$ will appear as a contiguous group at the low end, followed by every semiprime as a contiguous group, and so forth. In the case you give, it doesn't matter which of those terms is larger, so long as both of them are larger than all primes and smaller than all 3-almost primes.